# How to show hidden div on mouse over using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

I want to show hidden `div` on hover of `<div class="thumb">` and i have multiple `div` on page each thumb `div` has different content images. `width` is fix for all `div` but `height` of large div `<div class="large" style="display:none">` can be extended upon content after the image inside div.

Text of `h2` will be always the same in both `div`.

If mouse is inside <`div class="large"></div>` then the `div` should stay on screen.

```
<!-----------------  Small Boxes   ----------------->
<div class="thumb">
   <h2>Box1</h2>
   <img src="test_files/images/thumbnail/thumb1.png" />
</div>

<!-----------------  Large Boxes on hover  ----------------->
<div class="large" style="display:none">
   <h2>Box1</h2>
   <h3>Heading 3 (this text will come over the image)</h3>
   <img src="test_files/images/large/large1.png" />
   <p>
      Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
   </p>
</div>
```

I just given a example of one `div` but in actual I will have multiple boxes on actual page.

**Image to understand the question**

[image]

In actual page I will have multiple boxe like  this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.thumb').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).next().css('display', 'block');
});

$('.thumb').each(function(i, item) {
    $(this).next().mouseout(function() {
       $(this).css('display', 'none');
    });
});
```

Comment: Just tried this but `div#large`  keep flashing when i keep and move mouse inside this.

Comment: @jcubic - your code of 2nd attempt is not working at all. i'm using this http://pastesite.com/18523

Comment: I tried your third try http://pastie.org/1141321 it's working but in IE8 it's still flashing

Comment: maybe use mouseenter() and mouseleave() insted mouseover() and mouseout().

Comment: It's working but not with multiple instances I've code like this http://pastie.org/1141431

Comment: Will i have into set position into css for each box?